# JsPDF Compression generates blur PDF

Tags: canvas, compression, fabricjs, jspdf, pdf.js

I'm using [PDFJs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to annotate pdf using [fabric js](http://fabricjs.com/) and to save the result canvas images to pdf using [JsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

This is how I'm saving it:

```
 canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [width, height]);
    $.each(inst.fabricObjects, function (index, fabricObj) {
        if (index != 0) {
            pdf.addPage();
            pdf.setPage(index + 1);
        }
        var imgData = fabricObj.toDataURL({
            format: 'jpg',
            quality: 0.9
        });
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'jpg', 0, 0, width, height, null, 'FAST');
        //pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    });
 pdf.save("sample.pdf");
```

This results increase of PDF size from **3.12MB** to **11.2MB** and it looks blurred.

This code which I'm using earlier was saving the PDF with huge size

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF();
 $.each(inst.fabricObjects, function (index, fabricObj) {
     if (index != 0) {
        pdf.addPage();
        pdf.setPage(index + 1);
      }
   pdf.addImage(fabricObj.toDataURL(), 'JPG', 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 });
```

Original File Size: **3.12MB**

Saved PDF File Size : **213MB**